# Make my PC visible across all routers

Tags: networking, ubuntu, wireless-networking, router, ssh

So, recently ive found an old pc, installed lubuntu and set up a ssh server on it. My general purpose is to make a server for an old game on the old pc. Currently I have 3 routers at home. TP-Link Archer C2 is the main one, Archer C6 an extender and Linksys E900 is a router with wireless disabled in my room connected to C2 for Internet Access and then connecting 2 PCs in my room. Like a manual switch just with dynamic config, without extra settings. My question is, how can i connect with my main Ubuntu pc using ssh to the old server but not with my phone connected to Wifi on C2? Is there a way to enable some kind of cross connection, enabling me to connect to the server using my phone? 
Thanks in advance, sorry for a longer post.

Comment: That entirely depends how your routers are set up. If you've done this properly (no double NAT, wired backbone; though this is not easy to do with properietary firmware on home routers), and have a single segment for all your Wifi, it should work out of the box. If your setup is more complicated, we need to know your setup...

Comment: How can i help you more? Do I need to send a screen of what i have setup or navigating me (showing me a tutorial on how to do it) is enough?

Comment: I am kinda of a networking noob, dont really know what all these expressions like NAT and wired backbone mean so any kind of small help would be appreciated :D

Comment: Are you using the WAN/Internet port on your second and third router? Do your devices on different routers have different IP subnets (eg 192.168.1.x; 192.168.2.x)

Comment: Nevermind, the question was answered !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, the problem was already fixed.... I just had to disable DHCP on the E900 router and connect the cable from the C2 from WAN to LAN, then set a static ip address in the range of the C2 router and i could connect to my server from my phone inside my home network. Although the port forw. problem is still present since my ISP put another router outside my house to connect to their network (through air, since i dont have DSL nor Fibre internet), so ill be contacting them soon about that. 
Thanks for your time :D